# Camunda Spring Boot starter with embedded forms

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I am trying to use embedded forms with a start event with the Camunda spring boot starter.

My startEvent is described like this:

```
<bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="Rechnungseingang" camunda:formKey="embedded:app:forms/rechnungseingang.html">
  <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0dtfc1a</bpmn:outgoing>
</bpmn:startEvent>
```

The form itself is located under "src/main/webapp/forms/rechnungseingang.html", from my understanding this should be the correct path.

If I try to start the process after starting the spring boot app, I am receiving the error: "Form failure: The context path is either empty or not defined."

In the browser console, I can see a request to http://localhost:8080/test/api/engine/engine/default/process-definition/Rechnungseingang:1:927f0aa4-e590-11e7-973d-e2cbd8678b9f/startForm with the response:

```
{"key":"embedded:app:forms/rechnungseingang.html","contextPath":null}
```

Obviously the application can't handle the null value in the contextPath. How am I able to set the contextPath for Camunda in Spring Boot? In the application.properties I already tried to set `server.context-path` with no effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1.) there is no src/main/webapp with spring boot applications, use src/main/resources/static

2.) for camunda to link the resource to the engine, you will need a process application. This is done easily by adding "@EnableProcessApplication" to your spring boot app.

3.) Autodeployment requires a src/main/resources/META-INF/processes.xml file, but you can leave it empty

4.) there is a full example for embedded forms with camunda spring boot here: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-starter/example-twitter

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the combination of your points did the trick. I was expecting the starter to do the configuration for me (as there were already process definitions deployed and startable), but it seems a little configuration overhead still exists.

Comment: Has anything changed in newer versions? I had to change embedded:app:forms/rechnungseingang.html (using OP's example) to embedded:/forms/rechnungseingang.html, using full path instead of the app key for it to work.